# How to pack some object children in one object?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

After concat i have javascript:

```
Tasks={a:1,b:2},Tasks.Test={a:1,b:2},Tasks.Test.TestA={a:1,b:2},Tasks.TestB={a:1,b:2};
```

but i want:

```
Tasks={a:1,b:2,Test:{a:1,b:2,TestA:{a:1,b:2}},TestB:{a:1,b:2}};
```

how can i do it with grunt?

Comment: Those are functionally equivalent. Why do you want it differently? What code do you start with? Help us help you here, there isn't much to go on...

Comment: @AlexWayne i need it to minimize code. after uglify the same.

Comment: @askovpen So you want the second version because it's smaller?  So why not change the way you create that object in your source code?  I'm not sure any optimizer or minifier will transform this case into what you want.  _So what code do you start with?_

Comment: @AlexWayne Firefox `console.log(Tasks);` show minified :-)

Comment: Any object can be represented in this form, but we are talking about _building_ objects here.

Answer (score 0):

Minifiers should not change how your code executes.  So if you want a different structure, construct your object in a different way.

Let's say you start with this:

```
var Tasks = {a:1,b:2};
Tasks.Test = {a:1,b:2};

if (shouldIncludeTestA()) {
    Tasks.Test.TestA = {a:1,b:2};
}

if (shouldIncludeTestB()) {
    Tasks.TestB = {a:1,b:2};
}
```

Now the only reason to build your object like this is if certain parts it are dynamic, that is they might change at runtime. For instance, if `Tasks.Test.TestA` is sometimes blank and sometimes an object with more data in it.

So if you have code that controls how the object is built, you obviously cannot compress it into a single object literal, because that would mean stripping out the code that controls how the object is created.

On the other hand, if your object has the same structure everytime, just build it as a single object literal, and it will minify as a single object literal.

```
var Tasks = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    Test: {
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
        TestA: {
            a: 1,
            b: 2
        }
    },
    TestB: {
        a: 1,
        b: 2
    }
};
```

---

Compressors/minifiers try very hard not to change the logic of your code.  So if your logic builds up an object with multiple statements, your minified code *will contain multiple statements*.

So it seems to me that you are expecting the minifier to do something it will never do, and that it *should never do*.